# link cppuint library only when doing a "make check"

Tags: configuration, autoconf, automake

You can run unit tests in our application by doing a `make check`. However, the cppuint library is hardcoded into `LDFLAGS` in `Makefile.am`. Is there a way of linking in the cppuint library in `configure.am` *only* when doing a `make check` and not linking with when doing a regular `make`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing pre-canned.  You can probably do it with make tricks.

However, I would say you probably do not want to go this route.  Doing this means relinking on "make check" but also relinking again on "make all" or "make install".

Another approach would be to make your test suite use a special test version of the executable, with a different name.  And for this one you could use a per-target setting to add the library to the link flags.